# Not getting total value of input tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why my codes is not getting the total value of each row?, its getting only the first row value.

tried to insert it into .each function, but its not functioning

```
function calc_total()
{
  total=0;

  $('#po_total_amount').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val());
  });

  $('#totalPrice').val(total.toFixed(2));

}
```

get the grand total of each rows.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and edit your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quick, better answers from the community.
For starters, Please include a [mcve] to your question.  Otherwise it may be impossible to tell *exactly* where the issue lies.

Comment: Based on what I can see, you're iterating over all elements with the ID `po_total_amount`. But ID's **must** be unique, so you will only ever get one element this way.

Comment: ids are singular....

Answer (score 1):

You need to select your inputs differently so you can add their total. Id's must be unique so it won't let you `.each` a single element. If you give them each a class with the same name you can do it like this:

```js
var total = 0;
$('.po_total_amount').each(function() {
  total += parseInt($(this).val());
});

$('#totalPrice').val(total.toFixed(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="input" class="po_total_amount" value="2">
<input type="input" class="po_total_amount" value="2">
<input type="input" class="po_total_amount" value="4">
<input type="input" class="po_total_amount" value="90">
<input type="input" id="totalPrice">
```

Comment: No problem,  As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.